# Extended events file store with Azure blob storage

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage, sql-server-2016

I have created extended event for azure database using SQL server 2016 for which i am specifying event file from azure blob storage.

I have added credential in SQL server with storage access signature of respective blob container.
[image]

Whenever i start the session i get following error :

[image]

Any idea what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I have added credential in SQL server with storage access signature of respective blob container.

As far as I know, if we do not provide SQL credential or we do not store the correct shared access signature for the container in credential, the “The specified network password is not correct” error will be returned. According to your description, you have created a SQL Server credential using a shared access signature, but you still get “The specified network password is not correct” error, please make sure whether you specify read, write and list permissions for shared access signature and please ensure shared access signature does not reach the expiry time.

Comment: Thanks, Fred Han. 1.But when i run sql script 'select * from sys.credentials' on azure, its return an empty result.    2.Azure database V12 not supporting following server level creation of credential  'CREATE  CREDENTIAL [C_Name] 
   WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', 
   SECRET = 'Key'   
GO

Comment: Thanks, Fred Han. 
1.But when i run sql script 'select * from sys.credentials' on azure, its return an empty result.    
2.Azure database V12 not supporting following server level creation of credential  'CREATE CREDENTIAL [C_Name] 
   WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', 
   SECRET = 'Key'   
3.I am using following sql to create database level credential  'CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL [C_Name] 
   WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', 
   SECRET = 'Key'