# azure sql user permission

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to run following script to create credential for azure blob storage  on azure Master database with database admin account, but its giving me an error 'User does not have permission to perform this action'. 
Script : 
'
USE master
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL 'XYZ' 
   WITH IDENTITY='SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', 
   SECRET = 'shared access signature of blob storage'
GO '
[image]

Any idea?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You should create the database scoped user on your user Database. 
There are restrictions on 'master' in Azure SQL Database, even for DBA.

Comment: Thanks drediske,
Can you please look into following link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558012/extended-events-file-store-with-azure-blob-storage
if any suggest me